# pandas DataFrame: Line down in the Headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**EDIT:** the original Q was about changing colors to a column.. this is another issue

I'm trying to basically `\n` in the column headers as the image below.

So far I got this:

```
df.style.set_table_styles(
            [{'selector':'th',
             'props': [('background','#36304a'),
                       ('color','white'),
                       ('text-align','center')]},

             {'selector':'tr-nth-of-type(odd)',
             'props': [('background', '#d9d9d9')]},

             {'selector':'tr-nth-of-type(even)',
             'props': [('background', 'white')]},
             ])\
    .set_properties(subset=["Instument \n Name", "Etoro \n Symbol"], **{'text-align': 'left'})\
    .set_properties(subset=["#", "% Volume Above 20 Day \n Average","Yesterday's Percent \n Change"], **{'text-align': 'center'})\
    .format({'% Volume Above 20 Day \n Average': lambda x: '%.2f'%(x*100) +'%',
            "Yesterday's Percent \n Change": lambda x: '%.2f'%(x*100) +'%' })\
    .hide_index()
```

but it look like this (no line-down):
[image]

I want it to look like that (sorry for the poor quality):
[image]

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it with `style.applymap(func)`. See the official [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html).

```
def color_green(x):
    if x < 0.0:
        color = 'red'
    else:
        color = 'green'
    return 'color: %s' % color
df.style.applymap(color_green, subset=pd.IndexSlice[:,['Yesterday's Percent Change']])
```

Comment: Great! Works perfectly! Thank you very much

Comment: Is there a problem?

Comment: I can't figure how to '\n' down in the headers.. got any ideas?

Comment: `df.style.set_table_styles([dict(selector="th",props=[('max-width', '50px')])])` Does this setting work?

Comment: That's good to hear. Does it deserve recognition? LOL!

Comment: I mean.. It does what is supposed to do, but it isn't as the template..
On another note, where do you find documentation about the attributes of the methods? ( 'max-width' / subset.. etc)

Comment: I'm sure yours has already been confirmed, but I only know the official [reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html). I'll Google more than that.